# Image URL using Jsoup is not getting attached to NetworkImageView

Tags: java, android, jsoup, android-volley

In Json request, I am getting Image URL for particular article but `NetWorkImageView` is not getting that Image URL.
Here is my request:

```
JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                hidePDialog();
                JSONObject rss = response.getJSONObject("rss");
                JSONObject channel = rss.getJSONObject("channel");
                JSONArray item = channel.getJSONArray("item");
                Log.d(TAG, item.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < item.length(); i++) {


                    JSONObject obj = item.getJSONObject(i);
                    Movie movie = new Movie();
                    movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                    //Image Url
                    String imageLink = obj.getString("description");
                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(imageLink);
                    Element link = doc.select("img").first();
                    //System.out.println(link.absUrl("src"));

                    //ERROR comes with line below.
                    movie.setThumbnailUrl(link.absUrl("src"));
                    movieList.add(movie);

                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + volleyError.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();
        }
    });
 AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(objectRequest);
    return rootView;
}
```

It looks complete but I am still making silly mistake here. Getting silly `NullPointerException`. I trying it for some time now but stuck here for while now. Error is small but unable to find it though.

If you need more code snippets then let me know.
Your help will be very much appreciated. Sorry for dumb question.

**EDIT 1**
Logcat[image: Logcat]

Comment: On which line is that NullPointerException? Look in the logcat. It will tell you.

Comment: I mentioned in the code.. line `movie.setThumb.....`

Comment: So movie is null or link. Find out which one.

Comment: Neither movie nor link..When I run s.o.p(link.absUrl("src")) It gives me urls for all article images.

Comment: Or link.absUrl("src").

Comment: What is s.o.p? Then show the logcat.

Comment: No. Everything is good. S.o.p - System.out.println

Comment: Where is the connection with NetWorkImageView?

Comment: Please show the logcat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78115/discussion-between-roon13-and-greenapps).

Comment: @greenapps I updated my question with logcat.

Comment: @greenapps do you need more code?

Comment: @Roon13 Where did you initialize movieList variable ?

Comment: @Divers TopRatedFragment class

Comment: What is on TopratedFragment lines 76 and 55?

Comment: Line 55 is first line of code mentioned in the question and Line 76 is `movie.setThumb....`

Comment: @greenapps thank you for giving your time.

Comment: @Divers Check my answer. I was dying to tell you that link was not null. But   thank you. You pushed me so far. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you marked line 76 right - answer on your questions is that link is null because it not exist in your json string.

Comment: No link is not null. It gives me very nice Image URLs in Log but it is not getting atached

Comment: If it not null, then it means you mark wrong line. Or third case - it's a magic.

Comment: Let me try one more time. I will tell you

Comment: should i use old library?

Comment: How you can say that link is not null if I'm sure you don't know how to use debuger? Why you think that it not null?

Comment: There is one uncaught exception than NullpointerException. I know that I am committing silly mistake here. But Link is not null trust me

Comment: I never meant to insult you. Sorry.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But I think i should give another try.

Comment: Image URL i am getting are uneven. Every articles don't have images and i never caught that thing. so is the error. Sorry for trolling.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
               Element link = doc.select("img").first();
               movie.setThumbnailUrl(link.absUrl("src"));
```

I should have used:

```
                    Elements link = doc.select("img");
                    if(link.attr("src")!= null)
                    {
                        movie.setThumbnailUrl(link.attr("src"));
                    }
                    else {
                        movie.setThumbnailUrl(null);
                    }
```

Link was not null. My approach was wrong.

Comment: This code change should not make any difference while excuting your program.